# python threads and sqlite

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

Hi, what is the best way to do write to database using threads?  Will a simple lock when writing the data be enough or maybe there is a better way beside using threads?

I want to do something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue
import sqlite3

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, val,val2):
            ''' Constructor. '''

            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.val = val
            self.val2 = val2 

    def run(self):
            db = sqlite3.connect('C:\myDB.db')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            commandText='INSERT INTO Cars(name,carId) values({0} , {1})'.format(self.val, self.val2)

            cursor.execute(commandText)
            db.commit()


class MyThread2(Thread):
    def __init__(self, val,val2):
            ''' Constructor. '''

            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.val = val
            self.val2 = val2 

    def run(self):
            db = sqlite3.connect('C:\myDB.db')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            commandText='INSERT INTO Person(name,personId) values({0} , {1})'.format(self.val, self.val2)

            cursor.execute(commandText)
            db.commit()


if __name__=='__main__':

    db='C:\CMDB\CM.db'

    myThreadOb1 = MyThread("car1",8)
    myThreadOb1.setName('Thread 1')

    myThreadOb2 = MyThread2("mark",9)
    myThreadOb2.setName('Thread 2')

# Start running the threads!
    myThreadOb1.start()
    myThreadOb2.start()
```

Comment: Try using a queue, where you place SQL commands onto it and then have a single thread that executes them. Although I think SQLlite does have concurrency controls built into it

Comment: That's OK. SQLite DBMS can manage concurrency, although you can have at most one query running per connection.